# Test case for Camel Springboot application takes a longer build time

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel, camel-test

I have written camel test case for my spring boot application as below.

```
@RunWith(CamelSpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@UseAdviceWith

public class CamelTestClass {

    @Autowired
    private CamelContext camelContext;
    private String routeID = "routeId";
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(String.valueOf(CamelSpringBootApplication.class));


    @Test
    @DirtiesContext
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        ModelCamelContext mcc = camelContext.adapt(ModelCamelContext.class);
        RouteReifier.adviceWith(mcc.getRouteDefinition(routeID), mcc, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
               doSOmething
            }
        });
        mcc.start();
        assertion
        mcc.stop();
    }


    @Test
    @DirtiesContext
    public void test2() throws Exception {
        ModelCamelContext mcc = camelContext.adapt(ModelCamelContext.class);
        RouteReifier.adviceWith(mcc.getRouteDefinition(routeID), mcc, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
              doSomething
            }
        });
        mcc.start();
        assertion
        mcc.stop();
    }


    @Test
    @DirtiesContext
    public void test3() throws Exception {
        ModelCamelContext mcc = camelContext.adapt(ModelCamelContext.class);
        RouteReifier.adviceWith(mcc.getRouteDefinition(routeID), mcc, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                doSomething
            }
        });
        mcc.start();
        assertion
        mcc.stop();
    }
}
```

So there are 3 test cases written, On each beginning of the test case I had to start the camel context and clear it at the end. With this setup, On a maven build test tests are taking a long time to get it completed. with around 30 test cases, the build is taking 25 mins for completion. Is there a scope for optimization of test cases in terms of running time here?

Comment: Do you weave the routes the same in all your tests? If so, you could change the dirties context to `AFTER_CLASS`, though you need to make sure that the routes are only weaved once as each weaving would modify the route according to what you defined. In case of a forward to a mock endpoint i.e. via `.to("mock:done")` you'll receive n invocations of that endpoint in the n'th test! The weaving and the context start could be refactored to a `@BeforeEach` annotated method while the context stop could be done in an `@AfterEach` annotated method. Don't forget the flag to weave the route only once